# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [unresolved dependency: com.datastax.spark#spark-cassandra-connector_2.10;2.0.3: not found]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, datastax

I've installed on my Centos 7 machine :

> spark version 2.2.0
>
> scala version 2.11.8
>
> java version 1.8.0.0_144
>
> Cassandra 3.11.0

So the next step is configure spark to work with cassandra via the **`Spark Cassandra Connector`** , the **problem is** that when I try to run

`$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --packages datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:2.0.3-s_2.11`

**Note that** I tried also this :

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.10:2.0.3
```

I got :

```
...


                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

                ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

                :: com.datastax.spark#spark-cassandra-connector_2.10;2.0.3: not found

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


...

:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [unresolved dependency: com.datastax.spark#spark-cassandra-connector_2.10;2.0.3: not found]
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitUtils$.resolveMavenCoordinates(SparkSubmit.scala:1177)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:298)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:153)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

What I'm doing wrong ? I notice that those version that I'm using ( for scala, spark and cassandra) doesn't appears in the compatibility version here [spark-cassandra-connector github website](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector)

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the spark-cassandra-connector_2.10-2.0.3.jar file and adding it into the $SPARK_HOME/jars folder